# Docker Sidekiq as container not up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

I am new to docker. Required help to run sidekiq as a container.
I have a redis instance on AWS. I need to run sidekiq as a separate container so, I had done redis configuration in sidekiq.rb I had added sidekiq to docker-composer yml file. But still it is not getting up. 
Any reason?

Comment: Too less information in the question. Show the `sidekiq.rb` file and `docker-compose.yml` as well

Comment: I got it resolved :) Thanks

Comment: Great, do post the details as a answer